# use module.export with import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This line of codE:

```
module.exports = import("./src/client/Hello.js");
```

Is giving this error:

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

What am I doing wrong?

// Hello.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Bye from './Bye';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello
        <Bye/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also I am using webpack. Because of which Hello.js is transpiled.

Comment: We need to see how did you export your code in the hello.js file.

Comment: `import()` returns a promise.

Comment: 1) You shouldn't be using jQuery with React. 2) Just `import Hello from './path-to/Hello';` in the component file that needs it.

Comment: @Andy JQuery is for some testing purpose. Forgot to remove it here

Comment: @morganney Then what should I use against module.export

Comment: @Ndjxh you're already exporting the component (`export default class Hello`), so all you need to do is import it into the file that's going to be using it. Documentation on [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), and [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import).

Comment: @Andy then what should put in RHS of module.export

Comment: Why are you concentrating on the need to use `module.export`? You don't need it. You component is already being exported. As I commented above: import it straight into the file that needs it. @Ndjxh

Comment: @Andy I am using webpack's external which is accessing the file with `module.export` thats why I have to put something after this.
For more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74248640/include-file-using-module-export-on-browser

Comment: What is it that you will do with it after you import an export of import?

Answer (score -1):

You should import your component using `import`:

```
import Hello from "./Hello";
```

Read more about importing components here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/

Comment: against module.export ?

Comment: I want to know what can I put after this: `module.exports` = `????`